# How to make a open class to sealed class in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I have this below class, and I would like to make it a sealed class. How can I do it, and how to access this class from other classes?

```
open class Toy (var type: Type, var name : String) {

    open val source: String = ""

}
```

I can make it sealed class as below but how to Instantiate it?

```
   sealed class Toy (var type: Type, var name : String) {
    
        open val source: String = ""
    
    }
```

Comment: Why do you want to use a sealed class instead of a data or normal class?

Comment: I mean, just replace `open` with `sealed` on the first line, but your question doesn't necessarily sound clear on whether a sealed class will meet your needs.

Comment: @LouisWasserman, I can replace the open with sealed but I am having trouble accessing this sealed class form another class.

Comment: You'll need to be much more specific about what you mean by "accessing."  Are you trying to subclass it?  Instantiate it?

Comment: @LouisWasserman, I would like to instantiate it.

Comment: You can't.  `sealed` implies `abstract`.  You would need to have made a subclass and instantiated that.  (This is part of why I suspect `sealed` isn't right for your needs.  Are you just trying to make a non-subclassable class?  If so, you just delete `open` and write nothing else.)

Comment: How to make it a subclass and then instantiate it ?

Comment: I mean, you could have `sealed class Toy (var type: Type, var name: String)` and then have `class BoardGame(name: String): Toy(Type.BoardGame, name)` and then instantiate `BoardGame("Spirit Island")`.

Comment: @LouisWasserman, 
 I have open val source: String = "" inside the Toy class. With this suggested approach how could I have source val in my class.

Comment: What do you mean, "how could I have source val in my class"?  You'll already have a property with that name; you don't need to do anything special to get it.  If you provided examples of how you want to _use_ the classes, it'd be much easier to tell you how to achieve it.

Comment: @LouisWasserman, I am still not quite sure how did you pass the parameters. I am getting error on Toy(Type.BoardGame, name), it seems that we are not passing the correct parameters.

Comment: I mean, I'm just guessing how `Type` is defined, and what you want the subtypes of `Toy` to be like.  Without you telling us more about what you want, ideally with code, it's hard to guess the right solution to your problem -- but it definitely sounds like sealed classes are the wrong solution.

Comment: Can you give me the reason why sealed class is the wrong solution here.